# How to position a View to the right of a sibling's View child? Android XML

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Say I have the following XML

```
    <RelativeLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                          android:id="@+id/child1"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="2">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="15sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/child2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="2">
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/child1"/> // CAN'T DO THIS need work around

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have something similar to this. I have a `LinearLayout` with many children enclosed inside a `RelativeLayout`, and I have a `View` that overlaps child1 and child2. But I want it to only overlap child 2.

Is there any workaround to this?
I can post my actual code if needed, kinda wrote that on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

child1 is not in the same layout scope as the view that you want to use it in (at the line "//cant do this").

I'd suggest removing the linear layout and having both child1 and child2 in the parent relative layout.

Comment: Yes but then I won't be able to separate the inner children by weights, I'd have to use hardcoded width size.

Answer (score 0):

It's because child is not its sibling, Linearlayout is its sibling, if you want to move it to the right, try putting an id to the linearlayout and use it on android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/child1"

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_sibbling_view"
        android:background="@color/color_gray_400"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <TextView android:text="ABC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/child2"
            android:background="@color/mab_blue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View android:id="@+id/v_center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <View android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/v_center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/v_center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Right but then this wouldn't overlap child2 no?

Comment: Well, I have edited the answer but It's another kind of solution, I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I had to do this programatically. I calculated the width of the child1 column with

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                child1width = child1.getWidth();
                setMarkers(); // sets margin of View (the line)
            }
        });
```

and then added a left margin of child1Width to the View.